# Does Hikari Connection need test connection when starts the application?

Tags: spring, hikaricp

I configured Hikari following this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hikari

When Spring Boot starts Hikari starts too, as follows in the next image:
[image]

Is it possible to configure Hikari to start when the first ReST request is being received?

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from [Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)'s official document on Github:

> - connectionTestQuery
>     **If your driver supports JDBC4 we strongly recommend not setting this property.** This is for "legacy" drivers that do not support the JDBC4
>     Connection.isValid() API. This is the query that will be executed just
>     before a connection is given to you from the pool to validate that the
>     connection to the database is still alive. Again, try running the pool
>     without this property, HikariCP will log an error if your driver is
>     not JDBC4 compliant to let you know. Default: none

Comment: Sources proof: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.java#L168 and https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/PoolBase.java#L157

Answer (score 0):

As documentation:

"For a pooling DataSource to be created, we need to be able to verify that a valid Driver class is available, so we check for that before doing anything. In other words, if you set spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, then that class has to be loadable."(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)

Comment: How does this answer your own question?